# Unzipping directory structure with python

Tags: python, unzip

I have a zip file which contains the following directory structure:

```
dir1\dir2\dir3a
dir1\dir2\dir3b
```

I'm trying to unzip it and maintain the directory structure however I get the error:

```
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\\projects\\\testFolder\\\subdir\\\unzip.exe'
```

where testFolder is dir1 above and subdir is dir2.

Is there a quick way of unzipping the file and maintaining the directory structure?

Comment: Can you show your code ?

Comment: Also see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/339053/how-do-you-unzip-very-large-files-in-python/28766502?noredirect=1#comment59070684_28766502 (answer by Martijn)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The extract and extractall methods are great if you're on Python 2.6.  I have to use Python 2.5 for now, so I just need to create the directories if they don't exist.  You can get a listing of directories with the `namelist()` method.  The directories will always end with a forward slash (even on Windows) e.g.,

```
import os, zipfile

z = zipfile.ZipFile('myfile.zip')
for f in z.namelist():
    if f.endswith('/'):
        os.makedirs(f)
```

You probably don't want to do it *exactly* like that (i.e., you'd probably want to extract the contents of the zip file as you iterate over the namelist), but you get the idea.

Comment: Might want to wrap the `os.makedirs(f)` in a try: except (OSError,WindowsError): block in case the folders already exist.

Comment: but how to unzip files in the directory of "f"( os.makedirs(f) ) ??

Answer (score 16):

**Don't** trust extract() or extractall().

These methods blindly extract files to the paths given in their filenames. But ZIP filenames can be anything at all, including dangerous strings like “x/../../../etc/passwd”. Extract such files and you could have just compromised your entire server.

Maybe this should be considered a reportable security hole in Python's zipfile module, but any number of zip-dearchivers have exhibited the exact same behaviour in the past. To unarchive a ZIP file with folder structure safely you need in-depth checking of each file path.

Comment: Why not consider it a bug? Especially since it's "new" code, it was added for Python 2.6. To ship with that kind of hole is just stupid.

Comment: No reason to worry about security here, you would have to be Hulk Hogan to run your app under root privileges.

Comment: `etc/passwd` is just an example; there are many ways for a file dropped onto an arbitrary filesystem location to be a security risk without running as root. Classically dropping files like `something.php`, `.htaccess` etc into executable locations, or overwriting runtime data.

Comment: Looks like it has changed since 2.7.4: http://docs.python.org/2/library/zipfile#zipfile.ZipFile.extractall "The zipfile module attempts to prevent that."

Answer (score 8):

I tried this out, and can reproduce it.  The extractall method, as suggested by other answers, does **not** solve the problem.  This seems like a bug in the zipfile module to me (perhaps Windows-only?), unless I'm misunderstanding how zipfiles are structured.

```
testa\
testa\testb\
testa\testb\test.log
> test.zip

>>> from zipfile import ZipFile
>>> zipTest = ZipFile("C:\\...\\test.zip")
>>> zipTest.extractall("C:\\...\\")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "...\zipfile.py", line 940, in extractall
  File "...\zipfile.py", line 928, in extract
  File "...\zipfile.py", line 965, in _extract_member
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\...\\testa\\testb\\test.log'
```

If I do a `printdir()`, I get this (first column):

```
>>> zipTest.printdir()
File Name
testa/testb/
testa/testb/test.log
```

If I try to extract just the first entry, like this:

```
>>> zipTest.extract("testa/testb/")
'C:\\...\\testa\\testb'
```

On disk, this results in the creation of a folder `testa`, with a **file** `testb` inside.  This is apparently the reason why the subsequent attempt to extract `test.log` fails; `testa\testb` is a file, not a folder.

Edit #1: If you extract just the file, then it works:

```
>>> zipTest.extract("testa/testb/test.log")
'C:\\...\\testa\\testb\\test.log'
```

Edit #2: Jeff's code is the way to go; iterate through `namelist`; if it's a directory, create the directory.  Otherwise, extract the file.

Answer (score 7):

I know it may be a little late to say this but Jeff is right.
It's as simple as:

```
import os
from zipfile import ZipFile as zip

def extractAll(zipName):
    z = zip(zipName)
    for f in z.namelist():
        if f.endswith('/'):
            os.makedirs(f)
        else:
            z.extract(f)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    zipList = ['one.zip', 'two.zip', 'three.zip']
    for zip in zipList:
        extractAll(zipName)
```

Comment: it seems that `zipfile.ZipFile(zip_name).extractall()` does exactly that.

Answer (score 3):

There's a very easy way if you're using Python 2.6: the [extractall](http://docs.python.org/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.extractall) method.

However, since the `zipfile` module is implemented completely in Python without any C extensions, you can probably copy it out of a 2.6 installation and use it with an older version of Python; you may find this easier than having to reimplement the functionality yourself.  However, the function itself is quite short:

```
def extractall(self, path=None, members=None, pwd=None):
    """Extract all members from the archive to the current working
       directory. `path' specifies a different directory to extract to.
       `members' is optional and must be a subset of the list returned
       by namelist().
    """
    if members is None:
        members = self.namelist()

    for zipinfo in members:
        self.extract(zipinfo, path, pwd)
```

Comment: I tried this and unfortunately, I ran into the issues pointed to below.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you are trying to run unzip to extract the zip.

It would be better to use the python [`zipfile`](http://docs.python.org/library/zipfile.html) module, and therefore do the extraction in python.

```
import zipfile

def extract(zipfilepath, extractiondir):
    zip = zipfile.ZipFile(zipfilepath)
    zip.extractall(path=extractiondir)
```

Comment: Note that pwd is the file's password; the argument for the path to extract to is 'path'.

Comment: Sorry, my bad - you can tell I wrote the code without running it. :-)

Comment: Also it should be `zip = zipfile.ZipFile(zipfilepath)`

Answer (score 2):

### Filter namelist to exclude the folders

All you have to do is filter out the `namelist()` entries ending with `/` and the problem is resolved:

```
  z.extractall(dest, filter(lambda f: not f.endswith('/'), z.namelist()))
```

nJoy!

Answer (score 2):

If like me, you have to extract a complete zip archive with an older Python release (in my case, 2.4) here's what I came up with (based on Jeff's answer):

```
import zipfile
import os

def unzip(source_file_path, destination_dir):
    destination_dir += '/'
    z = zipfile.ZipFile(source_file_path, 'r')
    for file in z.namelist():
        outfile_path = destination_dir + file
        if file.endswith('/'):
            os.makedirs(outfile_path)
        else:
            outfile = open(outfile_path, 'wb')
            outfile.write(z.read(file))
            outfile.close()
    z.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

Note that zip files can have entries for directories as well as files. When creating archives with the `zip` command, pass the `-D` option to disable adding directory entries explicitly to the archive. When Python 2.6's `ZipFile.extractall` method runs across a directory entry, it seems to create a *file* in its place. Since archive entries aren't necessarily in order, this causes `ZipFile.extractall` to fail quite often, as it tries to create a file in a subdirectory of a file. If you've got an archive that you want to use with the Python module, simply extract it and re-zip it with the `-D` option. Here's a little snippet I've been using for a while to do exactly that:

```
P=`pwd` && 
Z=`mktemp -d -t zip` && 
pushd $Z && 
unzip $P/<busted>.zip && 
zip -r -D $P/<new>.zip . && 
popd && 
rm -rf $Z
```

Replace `<busted>.zip` and `<new>.zip` with real filenames relative to the current directory. Then just copy the whole thing and paste it into a command shell, and it will create a new archive that's ready to rock with Python 2.6. There *is* a `zip` command that will remove these directory entries without unzipping but IIRC it behaved oddly in different shell environments or zip configurations.