# Python zipfile removes execute permissions from binaries

Tags: python, python-2.7

Not sure why this is happening, but when I run unzip a file (e.g. apache-groovy-binary-2.4.7.zip) at the command line...

- directories are `rwx-r-xr-x`
- files are `rwxr-xr-x` or `rw-r--r--`

But when I run `zipfile.extractall()` from a Python 2.7 script on the same file...

- directories are `rwx-r-x---`
- files are all `rw-r----` - even the ones that should be executables as per above.

My `umask` setting is `0027`—this partly explains what's going on, but why is the executable bit being removed from all files?

What's the easiest fix to get Python adopting similar behaviour to the command-line version (apart from shelling out, of course!)?

Comment: Not sure if Python's implementation supports Zip's fileset property handling, but you should look in that direction. Here's how it works:

http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/zipfileset.html    <<< You're after 'filemode' and 'dirmode' parameters

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The reason for this can be found in the `_extract_member()` method in `zipfile.py`, it only calls `shutil.copyfileobj()` which will write the output file without any execute bits.

The easiest way to solve this is by subclassing `ZipFile` and changing `extract()` (or patching in an extended version. By default it is:

```
def extract(self, member, path=None, pwd=None):
    """Extract a member from the archive to the current working directory,
       using its full name. Its file information is extracted as accurately
       as possible. `member' may be a filename or a ZipInfo object. You can
       specify a different directory using `path'.
    """
    if not isinstance(member, ZipInfo):
        member = self.getinfo(member)

    if path is None:
        path = os.getcwd()

    return self._extract_member(member, path, pwd)
```

This last line should be changed to actually set the mode based on the original attributes. You can do it this way:

```
import os
import sys
from zipfile import ZipFile, ZipInfo

class MyZipFile(ZipFile):

    if sys.version_info < (3, 6):

        def extract(self, member, path=None, pwd=None):
            if not isinstance(member, ZipInfo):
                member = self.getinfo(member)
            if path is None:
                path = os.getcwd()
            ret_val = self._extract_member(member, path, pwd)
            attr = member.external_attr >> 16
            os.chmod(ret_val, attr)
            return ret_val

    else:

        def _extract_member(member, ZipInfo):
            if not isinstance(member, ZipInfo):
                member = self.getinfo(member)
            path = super(ZipFile, self)._extract_member(member, targetpath, pwd)

            if member.external_attr >  0xffff:
                 os.chmod(path, member.external_attr >> 16)
            return path


with MyZipFile('test.zip') as zfp:
    zfp.extractall()
```

(The above is based on Python 3.5 and assumes the zipfile is called `test.zip`)

Comment: Oh! This worked great: tested on python2.7. Thank you! @RCross, I recommend you hit the "Answer" checkmark on this.

Comment: According to a comment in https://bugs.python.org/issue15795, which describes the issue, I added a check for `attr` being nonzero before calling chmod()`.

Comment: That doesn't work in python 3.6 anymore, as it calls _extract_member instead of extract

Answer (score 18):

This works on python 3.6:

```
from zipfile import ZipFile, ZipInfo


class ZipFileWithPermissions(ZipFile):
""" Custom ZipFile class handling file permissions. """
    def _extract_member(self, member, targetpath, pwd):
        if not isinstance(member, ZipInfo):
            member = self.getinfo(member)

        targetpath = super()._extract_member(member, targetpath, pwd)

        attr = member.external_attr >> 16
        if attr != 0:
            os.chmod(targetpath, attr)
        return targetpath
```

Answer (score 3):

As noted by Rafael Almeida, extractall does not work on python 3.6.  A simple workaround is to also override the extractall method so that it calls extract instead of _extract_member.  Not clean, but working until ZipFile has a more comprehensive solution.

```
class MyZipFile(ZipFile):

    def extract(self, member, path=None, pwd=None):
        if not isinstance(member, ZipInfo):
            member = self.getinfo(member)

        if path is None:
            path = os.getcwd()

        ret_val = self._extract_member(member, path, pwd)
        attr = member.external_attr >> 16
        if attr != 0:
            os.chmod(ret_val, attr)
        return ret_val

    def extractall(self, path=None, members=None, pwd=None):
        if members is None:
            members = self.namelist()

        if path is None:
            path = os.getcwd()
        else:
            path = os.fspath(path)

        for zipinfo in members:
            self.extract(zipinfo, path, pwd)
```