# How to unzip specific folder from a .zip with Python

Tags: python

I am looking to unzip a particular folder from a .zip in Python:

e.g. `archive.zip` contains the folders `foo` and `bar`, I want to unzip `foo` to a specific location, retaining it's folder structure.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/639962/unzipping-directory-structure-with-python this question looks pretty similar

Comment: @cleg It's not, that question is just about retaining directory structure - which I know how to do. I want to know how to extract a particular folder from a zip.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Check [`zipfile`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile) module.

For your case:

```
import zipfile

archive = zipfile.ZipFile('archive.zip')

for file in archive.namelist():
    if file.startswith('foo/'):
        archive.extract(file, 'destination_path')
```

Comment: The first matching item returned by namelist() will be the folder 'foo/'. If that's likely to cause problems, you can just add something like if file.startswith('foo/') and file != 'foo/'

Comment: That works, but any way to extract the folder without its ancestors? E.g. if I want to extract `foo` from `archive.zip/foobar/bar/foo/`, the line `archive.extract(file, 'destination_path')` will extract to `destination_path/foobar/bar/foo/file`, while I would like it to extract to `destination_path/foo/file`

Comment: Incase any one else is facing the issue mentioned by `Alaa M`, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56362289/7073174) is a solution that worked for me

Answer (score 2):

You should close your zips....

---

```
import zipfile

archive = zipfile.ZipFile('archive.zip')

for file in archive.namelist():
    if file.startswith('foo/'):
        archive.extract(file, 'destination_path')

archive.close()
```

---

Or just use a safer method. With will close your zip.

```
import zipfile
with zipfile.ZipFile('archive.zip') as archive:
    for file in archive.namelist():
        if file.startswith('foo/'):
            archive.extract(file, 'destination_path')
```

Answer (score 1):

I like to reduce the list of names first so that the for loop doesn't parse through all the files in the zip archive:

```
import zipfile

archive = zipfile.ZipFile('archive.zip')

names_foo = [i for i in archive.namelist() if i.startswith('foo') ]

for file in names_foo:
    archive.extract(file)
```

Answer (score -2):

using zipfile library is very very slow.
this is better way:

```
os.system('unzip -P your-password path/to/file.zip')
```

Comment: Do you have proof that it's slower?