# Unzip part of a file using python gzip module

Tags: python, gzip, unzip

I am trying to unzip a gzipped file in Python using the gzip module. The pre-condition is that, I get 160 bytesof data at a time, and I need to unzip it before I request for the next 160 bytes. Partial unzipping is OK, before requesting the next 160 bytes. The code I have is

```
import gzip
import time
import StringIO

file = open('input_cp.gz', 'rb')
buf = file.read(160)
sio = StringIO.StringIO(buf)
f = gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=sio)
data = f.read()
print data
```

The error I am getting is IOError: CRC check failed. I am assuming this is cuz it expects the entire gzipped content to be present in buf, whereas I am reading in only 160 bytes at a time. Is there a workaround this??

Thanks

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/339053/how-do-you-unzip-very-large-files-in-python

Answer (score 4):

Create your own class with a read() method (and whatever else GzipFile needs from fileobj, like close and seek) and pass it to GzipFile. Something like:

```
class MyBuffer(object):
  def __init__(self, input_file):
    self.input_file = input_file

  def read(self, size=-1):
    if size < 0:
      size = 160
    return self.input_file.read(min(160, size))
```

Then use it like:

```
file = open('input_cp.gz', 'rb')
mybuf = MyBuffer(file)
f = gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=mybuf)
data = f.read()
```

Comment: No errors this time, but a blank line was o/p to console. Pretty sure 160b are enough to unzip. Also tried w/ 2000b

class MyBuffer(object):

    def __init__(self, input_file):

        self.input_file = input_file



    def read(self, size=-1):

        if size<0:

            size = 160

        return self.input_file.read(min(160,size))



    def tell(self):

        return



    def seek(self, start, end):

        return



    def close(self):

        return



file = open('input_cp.gz', 'rb')

mybuf = MyBuffer(file)

f = gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=mybuf)

data = f.read()

print data