# How to extract a large tar.gz avoding memory usage in Linux

Tags: python, memory, tar.gz

I have a tar.gz which has a large size (extracted file size is similar with 50GB), I want to extract it in Memory (or temp directory)
When I extract file into memory using below script, the server memory is fully used (server memory is 64GB, available memory is lower than it)

```py
import tarfile

with tarfile.open("large.tar.gz", "r") as tar:
    members = tar.getmembers()
    for member in members:
        f = tar.extractfilie(member)
        if f != None:
            txt = str(f.read(), "ISO-8859-1").replace('\t', ' ').splitlines()

    do_something(txt)
```

How can I extract it to avoid memory full ?
(don't care to extracting memory or temp directory)
Thanks.

Comment: See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/339053/how-do-you-unzip-very-large-files-in-python